# Is Django ModelFormSet using up all my memory? Similar to a memory leak

Tags: django, memory-leaks, django-forms

I have a Django view that begins as follows:

```
def MyView(request):
    formset = MyModelFormSet(request.POST)
    ...
```

Obviously, there is more code in the view than what I've shown. My question is specific to the `MyModelFormSet`.  My problem is Django is using all the memory* when the view is called.

Is it possible that `MyModelFormSet` is pulling every "`MyModel`" from the database?  Do I need to provide a `queryset` argument to `MyModelFormSet`?

*This would not technically be a memory leak, but it initially seemed like one to me and so referring to it as a memory leak might help others find this question and solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question.  I couldn't find this information pointed out clearly anywhere else, and hopefully this Q/A will be helpful to others.

**Yes**, `MyModelFormSet` is pulling every "`MyModel`" from the database.  I verified this in a test environment which had 15,000 `MyModel`s in the database. I observed the following:

1) I submitted only 3 MyModels forms in a HTTP post. After the post:

2) `formset.forms` contains 3 `MyModelForm`s.

3) `len(formset._queryset)` equals 15,000. `formset._queryset` contains a list of every `MyModel` in the database. Django has pulled every `MyModel` and stored it in memory.

The solution is to provide a `queryset` argument. You can read more about this in the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-queryset).

This test was performed with Django version 1.4.5.